# Using AWK to add two parameter into a config inside a double quotes

Tags: awk, double-quotes

I Would like to use a awk or sed command and produce a script for hardening the /etc/default/grub file:

**the original config file is like this:**

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto resume=/dev/mapper/vg00-swap rd.lvm.lv=vg00/root rd.lvm.lv=vg00/swap rhgb quiet"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=true
```

and would like to add "ipv6.disable=1 audit=1" inside the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX= 
the problem is the config is quoted inside a double quote , therefore i cannot output it successfully with a awk command

**The Desired output is as follow:**

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
    GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
    GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
    GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
    GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto resume=/dev/mapper/vg00-swap rd.lvm.lv=vg00/root rd.lvm.lv=vg00/swap rhgb quiet ipv6.disable=1 audit=1"
    GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
    GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=true
```

**What I had tried is as follow, but the resulting parameter is not inside the double quote:**

`awk '/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX/{$0=$0" ipv6.disable=1 audit=1"}{print}' /etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto resume=/dev/mapper/vg00-swap rd.lvm.lv=vg00/root rd.lvm.lv=vg00/swap rhgb quiet" ipv6.disable=1 audit=1
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=true
```

Anyone please can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to match the end quote and replace it with `ipv6.disable=1 audit=1"`

```
awk '/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX/{sub("\"$", " ipv6.disable=1 audit=1\"")}1'/etc/default/grub
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ awk '/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX/{sub("\"$", " ipv6.disable=1 audit=1\"")}1' /etc/default/grub
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto resume=/dev/mapper/vg00-swap rd.lvm.lv=vg00/root rd.lvm.lv=vg00/swap rhgb quiet ipv6.disable=1 audit=1"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=true
```

Comment: can you provide a complete awk command to do this? thanks a lot

Comment: not sure what you mean by "complete awk command", the command I gave is exactly what you would use.

Comment: can you tell me the logic behind the command you are using? just wanted to know more on awk command